# How would changing social media description=meta description affect site's SEO?

Tags: meta-description

I want to change the website's social media descriptions equal to the meta description of every page. Will this affect the site in a positive way since we have meta description for every page?

Comment: The only time the social media descriptions effect your site is when your site is shared on social media.   Is your meta description better than what Facebook currently shows when your pages are shared?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Yes. Meta descriptions and short and to the point.

Comment: I am confused reading this. Are you talking about OpenGraph `og:description` or description meta tag `<meta name="description" content="My Site is better than yours.">`?

Comment: @closetnoc: I am talking about both. Trying to make og:description equal to meta descriptions.

Comment: Okay. I get it! Now that I reread your question, it seems obvious. Sorry. OpenGraph has nothing to do with SEO. So both matching will not effect anything. However, you do have to craft your description meta-tags well. You should do this for OG as well. I assume a well crafted description meta-tag will help with OG if you simply copy the description meta-tag. Cheers!!